# Upload pdf file to s3 using nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want to upload a pdf to s3 using the `aws-sdk` package and nodejs. I am encoding the pdf from my client application to a base64 string and decoding it on the serverside.

The file encoding is as follows:

```
const base64 = btoa(reader.result)
```

The decoding is as follows:

```
const convertBase64ToPdf = async (file) => {
  const byteCharacters = atob(file)

  const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length)

  for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
    byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i)
  }

  const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers)
  return byteArray
}
```

I am defining the params as follows:

```
const params = {
  Bucket: BUCKET,
  Key: `${RAW_POLICIES}${s3Name}`,
  Body: doc,
  ContentType: 'application/pdf',
  Tagging: tagString,
  ContentDisposition: 'inline',
}
```

and the upload is as follows:

```
s3.upload(params, (err, response) => {
   if (err) {
      console.log(err)
   } else {
      console.log(`File uploaded successfully. File URL: ${response.Location}`)
   }
 })
```

and I'm retrieving the resulting URL as follows:

```
const signedUrl = await s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
    Bucket: BUCKET,
    Key: `${RAW_POLICIES}${s3Name}`,
})
```

The file is technically being uploaded however it is not a viewable pdf file. Unfortunately, i am unable to convert it to a file via `File` since that is a client-side library and not in node. Likewise, `aws-sdk` doesn't accept a `Blob`. Is there a way to send a `Buffer` or `Uint8Array` to s3 and have it be pdf file that can be opened?

Comment: Key: `${RAW_POLICIES}${s3Name}`, -- does this contain file extension?

Comment: @Arman yes. It adds `.pdf` to the end of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the following? [Refer here for original post](https://hashnode.com/post/upload-pdf-files-to-s3-bucket-ckuhzgz8k0ddi8ws19qfydpu9)

```
  const base64 = req.body;
  const base64Data = Buffer.from(base64.replace(/^data:application\/\w+;base64,/, ""), "base64");
  const params = {
    Bucket: "my-bucket-name,
    Key: Date.now().toString() + ".pdf", // some uuid
    Body: base64Data,
    ContentEncoding: "base64", // required
    contentType: "application/pdf",
  };

  const uploaded = await S3.upload(params).promise();
  res.status(200).json({ uploaded });
```

Comment: So it is processing the file as a PDF however it still fails to open it. I get an error saying "Error: Failed to load PDF document." which makes me think the actual pdf content is invalid or not correctly formatted.

Comment: After looking at the original post, turns out i was performing the encoding incorrectly by using the `btoa` function and should've just used the `readAsDataUrl` method. Making that change along with your answer worked.